# MySql: Как продублировать несколько строк и отсортировать учитывая новый результат?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pagination, doctrine

Ребята есть работающий SQL:

**Symfony 1.4 :**

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('TechAnalys ta')
            ->leftJoin('ta.Translation tatr')
            ->leftJoin('ta.TCInstrument tci')
            ->leftJoin('tci.primarygroup cat')
            ->andWhere('ta.isActive=?', 1)
            ->andWhereIn('tatr.lang', $this->trans_langs)
            ->andWhere('tatr.isTActive =?', 1)
            ->orderBy('ta.created_at DESC');

private function getPager($query, $page) {
    $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('TechAnalys', 10);
    $pager->setQuery($query);
    $pager->setPage($page);
    $pager->init();
    return $pager;
}
```

**Resultat:**

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  techanalys t 
  LEFT JOIN techanalys_translation t2 
ON t.id = t2.id 
  LEFT JOIN t_c_instrument t3 
ON t.t_c_instrument_id = t3.id 
  LEFT JOIN trading_condition_groups t4 
ON t3.primarygroupid = t4.id 
WHERE (
t.isactive = 1 
AND t2.lang IN ('en')
AND t2.istactive = 1
  )
ORDER BY t.created_at DESC
```

То Есть будет выведено похожее

```
id        title      isretro      created_at     updated_at
1         aaa        0            2017-01-10     2017-01-10
2         bbb        1            2017-01-09     2017-01-09
3         ccc        0            2017-01-08     2017-01-08
4         ddd        1            2017-01-07     2017-02-01
5         eee        1            2017-01-06     2017-02-10
```

В таблице `techanalys t` есть колонка `isretro` со значением 0 или 1,и колонка `updated_at` показывает когда она создана.

**Надо сделать следующее:**
представь что есть 5 записи.где 3 строчки надо продублировать и прибавить к основному результату.То Есть получается 6 строчек.и отсортировать их учитывая сначала updated_at у isretro

Из основного запроса выбрать те которые `isretro` и прибавить к основному результату. Для `isretro` -> `updated_at`,а для обычных -> created_at.Получается дублировать эту строку и вставить в соответствующее место учитывая их время.Приоритет у `isretro`.

Если бы в этом запросе суметь выбрать отдельно те которые `isretro` и объединить вместе с основным результатом учитывая дату было бы супер.

Может показав результат который хочу получить боле точнее выразит то что хочу :

```
id        title      isretro      created_at     updated_at
5         eee        1            2017-01-06     2017-02-10
4         ddd        1            2017-01-07     2017-02-01
1         aaa        0            2017-01-10     2017-01-10
2         bbb        1            2017-01-09     2017-01-09
2         bbb        1            2017-01-09     2017-01-09
3         ccc        0            2017-01-08     2017-01-08
4         ddd        1            2017-01-07     2017-02-01
5         eee        1            2017-01-06     2017-02-10
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Описание и пример полны противоречий. Почему к результирующему набору не добавилось id=5? там isretro=1 и updated_at>created_at... почему добавилось id=2? там updated_at=created_at...

Comment: @Akina я исправил вопрос(id=5), а id=2 верно,ведь его  updated_at < чем id=1 created_at

Comment: _его updated_at < чем id=1 created_at_ Наверное, в этой фразе есть какой-то смысл... но я его понять не в силах.

Comment: @Akina Я поправил вопрос, это моя вина,неправильно сформулировал.

Comment: С тем, какие записи выбираются дополнительно, вроде понятно - те, у которых isretro=1. А вот итоговый порядок записей совершенно непонятен...

Comment: @Akina представь что есть 4 записи.где 2 строчки надо продублировать и прибавить к основному результату.То Есть получается 6 строчек.и отсортировать их учитывая сначала updated_at у isretro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sq.id, sq.title, sq.isretro, sq.created_at, sq.updated_at
FROM
    (
    SELECT id, title, isretro, created_at, updated_at, 1 num
    FROM test
  UNION ALL
    SELECT id, title, isretro, created_at, updated_at, 2
    FROM test
    WHERE isretro=1
    ) sq
ORDER BY CASE num 
         WHEN 2 THEN GREATEST(sq.updated_at, sq.created_at) 
         ELSE sq.created_at 
         END DESC;
```

Запрос даст неверный результат, если есть записи, для которых updated_at < created_a. Лечится соотв. корректировкой CASE для num=2.

Comment: А говорил не понял :) Спасибо большое